# Running leaflet on nodejs server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet

I tried to run leaflet on a nodejs server side without success. I build it with jake as described in the download section, but then, when I require leaflet on a server file, if I start my node server, it crash with this error :

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

Thanks node, I know it. But Is there a way to use leaflet on server side ? I need it for some operation on a L.geojson (https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) and I can't manage to do it without the "L" reference.

I'll appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Comment: As recommended by the leaflet author, point in polygon is just some code without deps needed. So he recommends me to use libs like turf (http://github.com/Turfjs/turf-inside) and avoid leaflet on server side. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vanilla Leaflet does not work in node. I've made a wrapper here: https://github.com/jieter/leaflet-headless

Comment: Seems what I want. I just have some issues on Windows, I miss some deps (MS Visual studio...) but If someone have another solution as good as this one, I'm still looking at this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You can load leaflet in node.js by simulating the browser:

```
// Create globals so leaflet can load
global.window = {
  screen: {
    devicePixelRatio: 1
  }
};
global.document = {
  documentElement: {
    style: {}
  },
  getElementsByTagName: function() { return []; },
  createElement: function() { return {}; }
};
global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'nodejs',
  platform: 'nodejs'
};
global.L = require('leaflet');
```

I used this in conjunction with [Point in Polygon for Leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip/).

Comment: You should also add `devicePixelRatio: 1` inside `window` and also `platform: 'nodejs'` under `navigator` to allow newer versions of Leaflet to be loaded properly.

Comment: 'GLOBAL' is deprecated, use 'global' instead

Comment: `node --require node_modules/jsdom-global/register`