# Leaflet.js in Node.js to create Map Screenshot on pure backend solution

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet

I would like to use leaflet.js inside node.js to create a map screenshot with a geoJSON (polygon) on it. As the question title already explains, I would like to create this screenshot without any involvement of a frontend (browser), so we are not talking about showing the map to any user in a browser, but to simply render a screenshot with that geoJSON as a pure backend solution.

I have used leaflet.js before (on the frontend side only), and I know that the "SimpleMapScreenshoter" module is able to capture screenshots (even with geoJSON stuff on the map), but I'm suspicious if this will work without the use of a browser...

Does anybody know if this can be done inside node.js without any browser involvement?

Does anybody have some working code or can provide me an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running leaflet on nodejs server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28167343/running-leaflet-on-nodejs-server-side)

Comment: thank you kennarddh, this is for sure interesting and a good starting point. But it doesn't address the screenshot part. So it answers my question partially.

Comment: https://github.com/jieter/leaflet-headless

Comment: Cool! That is even more interesting as it comes with a "save image" function already implemented! Let me check this out. Kudos to you @kennarddh. I've googled that stuff for nearly an hour before I posted here.